# My Cisco Netgear

Tags: networking, wireless, wine

I have a desktop no working lan cable and my router doesn't read them so I use a cisco netgear. The problem is when I installed ubuntu that I can't get it to recognize my cisco so I can access the internet and install wine properly. I tried using a usb by downloading wine onto it in windows and installing it in ubuntu but it has to get access to the internet so I can't access wine to run the cisco install or the cisco period. anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you install it in about one hour:

- Get into your car
- buy a network cable,
- drive back home,
- do an automatic update
- done!

Here is how to do it in about one week... (maybe).

- Go to a computer that has an internet connection and surf here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/
- Select Trusty in the drop-down box.
- Search for the right drivers.
- Be sure to locate their dependencies and the dependencies of the dependencies.
- Be sure to download the correct version, either 32- or 64-bit.
- Once you've download about fifteen or so packages on another computer, transfer them with a USB stick or similar to the desktop of your Ubuntu computer. Open a terminal and install them...

It may complain that a package is missing a dependency. If so, download that and add it to the desktop and try again.

Write many posts on Ask Ubuntu to tell everyone how you're stuck. Rinse and repeat.